# Best Schema to represent NCAA Basketball Bracket

Tags: sql, database-design, language-agnostic, database-agnostic

What is the best database schema to represent an NCAA mens basketball bracket? Here is a link if you aren't familiar: http://www.cbssports.com/collegebasketball/mayhem/brackets/viewable_men

I can see several different ways you could model this data, with a single table, many tables, hard-coded columns, somewhat dynamic ways, etc.  You need a way to model both what seed and place each team is in, along with each game and the outcome (and possibly score) of each.  You also need a way to represent who plays who at what stage in the tournament.

In the spirit of March Madness, I thought this would be a good question.  There are some obvious answers here, and the main goal of this question is to see all of the different ways you could answer it.  Which way is best could be subjective to the language you are using or how exactly you are working with it, but try to keep the answers db agnostic, language agnostic and fairly high level. If anyone has any suggestions on a better way to word this question or a better way to define it let me know in the comments.

Comment: Since there cannot be a 'one-true' answer, I would suggest making it a community wiki question.

Comment: I don't know that there can't be one true answer.  I would agree that the answer could be subjective, but I think there will be one answer that is clearly the best way to do it for the majority of applications, don't you think?  If it turns out that way I would make it a CW entry.

Comment: To be clear, I am not developing a bracket application.  My intention here is to use this as a way to figure out the best way to model a real world application in a normalized database that doesn't have a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a RDBMS, I think the simplest approach that's still flexible enough to accommodate the majority of situations is to do the following:

- **Teams** has *[team-id (PK)]*, *[name]*, *[region-id (FK to **Regions**)]*, *[initial-seed]*. You will have one entry for each team. (The regions table is a trivial code table with only four entries, one for each NCAA region, and is not listed here.)
- **Participants** has *[game-id (FK to **Games**)]*, *[team-id (FK to **Teams**)]*, *[score (nullable)]*, *[outcome]*. *[score]* is nullable to reflect that a team might forfeit. You will have typically have two Participants per Game.
- **Games** has *[game-id (PK)]*, *[date]*, *[location]*. To find out which teams played in a game, look up the appropriate game-id in the Participants table. (Remember, there might be more than two teams if someone dropped out or was disqualified.)

To set up the initial bracket, match the appropriate seeds to each other. As games are played, note which team has *outcome = Winner* for a particular game; this team is matched up against the winner of another game. Fill in the bracket until there are no more winning teams left.

Comment: I like this, but how would you know, looking at the data, how to match teams up?  For instance, you need to know if they are midwest, west, east or south, and would you just rely on the programming to know that a 1 seed plays a 16 seed? how do you know though for sure who the winner plays?

Comment: Yes, I'd say that a rule like "the 1 seed plays 16 seed" is something that should be codified into business logic, not stored in the database. I did forget about the different regions, though; I'll amend that.

Comment: More specifically, the rule is that if the highest-numbered seed is N, where N is a power of 2, then the seed numbered k plays the seed numbered N - k + 1 in the initial matchup. (For example, seed k = **4** plays seed 16 - 4 + 1 = **13** in a 16-seed matchup.)

Comment: Right, but that rule only lets you figure out the starting bracket.  How do you say that the winner of the 16 vs 1 plays the winner of the 8 vs 9?

Comment: That's just a re-application of the rule with N being half as large as it was before. Do you see why?

Comment: If not, just assign a number i = 1 ... N/2 to each matchup. In the next round, the winner of matchup i plays the winner of i + 1 if is i is odd, or the winner of i - 1 if i is even.

Comment: At some point you're going to have to include code in your solution. You seem to be asking how to put matching logic in the db. You don't. Put the logic in code, store enough data in the db to drive your code. Problem solved, where's my bounty.

Comment: @Peter: Yep; that's why I said "Yes, I'd say that a rule like "the 1 seed plays 16 seed" is something that should be codified into business logic, not stored in the database."

Comment: Anyone factoring the play-in game into this?  Or is that out of scope? :)

Answer (score 12):

The natural inclination is to look at a bracket in the order the games are played. You read the traditional diagram from the outside in. But let's think of it the other way around. Each game is played between two teams. One wins, the other loses.

Now, there's a bit more to it than just this. The winners of a particular pair of games face off against each other in another game. So there's also a relationship between the games themselves, irrespective of who's playing in those games. That is, the teams that face off in each game (except in the first round) are the winners of two earlier games.

So you might notice that each game has two "child games" that precede it and determine who faces off in that game. This sounds exactly like a binary tree: each root node has at most two child nodes. If you know who wins each game, you can easily determine the teams in the "parent" games.

So, to design a database to model this, you really only need two entities: `Team` and `Game`. Each `Game` has two foreign keys that relate to other `Game`s. The names don't matter, but we would model them as separate keys to enforce the requirement that each game have no more than two preceding games. Let's call them `leftGame` and `rightGame`, to keep with the binary tree nomenclature. Similarly, we should have a key called `parentGame` that tracks the reverse relationship.

Also, as I noted earlier, you can easily determine the teams that face off in each game by looking at who won the two preceding games. So you really only need to track the winner of each game. So, give the `Game` entity a `winner` foreign key to the `Team` table.

Now, there's the small matter of seeding the bracket. That is, modeling the match-ups for the first round games. You could model this by having a `Game` for each team in the overall competition where that team is the `winner` and has no preceding games.

So, the overall schema would be:

```
Game:
    winner: Team
    leftGame: Game
    rightGame: Game
    parentGame: Game
    other attributes as you see fit

Team:
    name
    other attributes as you see fit
```

Of course, you would add all the other information you'd want to the entities: location, scores, outcome (in case the game was won by forfeit or some other out of the ordinary condition).

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specify RDBMS, I'm gonna be a little different and go with a CouchDB approach since I was reading about that this weekend.  Here's the document structure I've come up with a represent a game.

```
{
  "round" : 1, //The final would be round 5, and I guess Alabama St. vs. Morehead would be 0
  "location" : "Dayton, OH",
  "division": "South",
  "teams" : ["UNC", "Radford"]  //A feature of Couch is that fields like teams don't need a fixed nuber of columns.
  "winner" : "UNC"  //Showing my bias
}
```

A more interesting or complete application might have data for teams, rankings, and the like stored somewhere as well.  John's approach covers that angle well, it seems.  I welcome any comments from people who know better on my Couch skills.

Answer (score 2):

I created a small system with the following tables:

Games: GameId, TournId, RoundId, Sequence, Date, VisitorId, VisitorScore, HomeId, HomeScore, WinnerId, WinnerGameId, WinnerHome (bit)

Predictions: PredId, UserId, GameId, PredVisitorId, PredHomeId, PredWinnerId

Rounds: RoundId, TournId, RoundNum, Heading1, Heading2

Teams: TeamId, TournId, TeamName, Seed, MoreInfo, Url

Tournaments: TournId, TournDesc

Users: TournId, UserName

WinnerGameId connects the winner of a game to their next game.  WinnerHome tells whether the winner is the home or visitor of that next game.  Other than that, I think it's pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

**4 tables:**

**Team**(Team, Region, Seed)

**User**(UserId, Email, blablabla)

**Bracket**(BracketId, UserId, Points)

**Pick**(BracketId, GameId, Team, Points)

Each bracket a person submits will have 63 rows in the Pick table.
After each game is played you would update the pick table to score individual picks. Points field in this table will be null for game not yet played, 0 for an incorrect pick or positive number for correct pick.  GameId is just a key identifying where in that users bracket this pick goes (ex: East_Round2_Game2, FinalFour_Game1).

The points column in the bracket table can be updated after each update of the pick table so it contains the sum of points for that bracket.  The most looked at thing will be the standings, don't want to re-sum those every time someone wants to view the leader board.

You don't need to keep a table with all the games that actually get played or their results, just update the pick table after each game.  You can even do the bracket highlighting of correct/incorrect picks by just looking at the Points column in the pick table.

Answer (score 1):

### Proposed Model

[Proposed ER Diagram http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/1464/ncaaer.jpg](http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/1464/ncaaer.jpg)

### Team Table

All we need to know about a team is the name and seed. Therefore we need a "Team" table to store the seed value. The only candidate key is team name so we will use that as the primary to keep things simple. NCAA team names are unlikely to change over the course of a single tournament or contain duplicates so it should be an adequate key.

### MatchUp Table

A "MatchUp" table can be used to pair the teams into each of the match ups. Foreign Keys (FK1, FK2) to the "Team" will ensure that the teams exist and a primary key over these values ensures that teams are only matched up against each other once.

A foreign key (FK4) to the "Team" table from the "MatchUp" table will record the winner. Logically the winner would need to be one of the two teams participating in the match up. A check constraint against the primary key could ensure this.

Once the outcome of a match up has been determined the Victor's seed could be retrieved from the team table in order to compare against other Victor's in order to determine subsequent match ups. Upon doing so an FK (FK3) to the resulting match up can be written to the determining match ups in order to depict the progress of the tournament (although this data could probably be derived at any time).

### Games Table

I also modeled out the games of each Match Up. A game is identified by the match up it is a part of and a sequence number based on the order in which it took place during the match up. Games have a winner from the team table (FK2). Score could be recorded in this table as well.

Comment: Your name is Blake Taylor and you're answering a question about the NCAA basketball tournament? That's quite a coincidence, unless it's not. :)

Answer (score 1):

In keeping track of a large number of different bracket predictions: You could use 67 bits for keeping track of the outcome of each game. (ie. Each of the sixty-seven games played in the tournament is each represented by a bit, 1 = "team A wins", 0 = "team B wins").  To display any given bracket, you can use a pretty simple function to map the 67 bits to the UI. The function knows the team names and their initial location, and then it tracks their movement through the bracket as it traces the 'bitboard'.

Answer (score -4):

I use the same schema for all of my databases.

```
t
--------
1 guid PK
2 guid FK
3 bit
```

Then in my code:

```
select [2],[3] from t where [1] = @1
```

@1 is the id of the data I am fetching. Then if [2] is not null, I select again, setting @1 to [2].

This makes it really easy to model the situation you posted.